# $c$ is the cardinal of real numbers, prove $c+c=c$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

$c$ is the cardinality of real numbers. To prove that $c+c=c$ we need to show that $c+c$ is less or equal to $c$ and vice versa.
Since $c$ is a cardinal number I choose $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ (separate sets) as the sets where their cardinals are $c$. Now where do I go?
I know that $(0,1)\sim (a,b)$ and maybe this can help to complete the proof.
Can anyone give a hint??

Comment: If you know an interval has cardinality $\mathfrak c$ just look at $(0,2)$ compared to $(0,1)+(1,2)$.  The difference is just one point.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$(0,1) \subset (0,1)\cup(0,2) \subset (0,2) \sim (0,1)$
we have
$c \leq c+c \leq c,$
so $c+c=c.$